# TypeError: Cannot read property 'maps' of undefined (Google maps places autocomplete Angular 2)

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps

I am trying to use the google maps auto complete with Angular 5, i followed this tutorial in http://myangularworld.blogspot.com.eg/2017/07/google-maps-places-autocomplete-using.html, and after running for some reason it is not able to identify google

these are my imports:

```
import { .... NgZone }
import { MapsAPILoader } from '@agm/core';
import { } from '@types/googlemaps';
import { google } from '@agm/core/services/google-maps-types';
```

here is the  injections:

```
constructor(
private mapsAPILoader: MapsAPILoader,
private ngZone: NgZone) {
```

}

and here is the main funtion inside ngonit:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
  const autoComplete = new google.maps.places.AutoComplete(this.searchElement.nativeElement, { types: ['address'] });
  autoComplete.addListener('place_changed', () => {
    this.ngZone.run(() => {
      const places: google.maps.places.PlaceResult = autoComplete.getPlace();
      if (places.geometry === undefined || places.geometry === null) {
        return;
      }
    });
  });
});
```

and here is the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'maps' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

Let’s take a look at it:

```
...
// import this two modules and all should be fine.
import { } from 'googlemaps';
import { MapsAPILoader } from '@agm/core';
...
constructor(
    private mapsAPILoader: MapsAPILoader,
    private ngZone: NgZone
  ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
  const autoComplete = new google.maps.places.AutoComplete(this.searchElement.nativeElement, { types: ['address'] });
  autoComplete.addListener('place_changed', () => {
    this.ngZone.run(() => {
      const places: google.maps.places.PlaceResult = autoComplete.getPlace();
      if (places.geometry === undefined || places.geometry === null) {
        return;
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Also, you need to install next npm's:

```
$ npm install @agm/core --save
$ npm install @types/googlemaps --save-dev
```

I hope it will help you.
http://brianflove.com/2016/10/18/angular-2-google-maps-places-autocomplete/

**UPD**

I created a stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5-example-zswbff
For me, all works fine.

Do you use webpack, angular/cli?

Comment: Yes I made sure i installed it i even uninstalled it and installed again, still same error i also followed the above link, nearly same code, but i noticed something, should i find the @types/googlemaps in the node_modules ? cuz it is not there

Comment: I found @types/googlemaps in the dev dependencies in the package.json folder , but still giving me the same errors

Comment: @M.Gamie I created a stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5-example-zswbff For me, all works fine.

Comment: hey Taras Yes I use webpack, angular/cli, I even tried your sample code still throwing me the same error!!!

Comment: @M.Gamie On the stackblitz  all works fine, you need just put your api_Key

Comment: is there an option to retrieve the location data in different language ?

Comment: @M.Gamie I think this new one question and not related to this.

Comment: thanks Taras, yes it is different , I will post it in another question

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, i used :

```
declare var google
```

instead of :

```
import { google } from '@agm/core/services/google-maps-types'
```

and it just worked fine, I don't have a clear explanation to this but it just worked

Comment: It's lifehack, and I don't recommend using it on PROD. Its mean you try to get the google object from global objects. can be conflicts or incorrect behavior

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you didn't npm install the type, try:

`npm install @types/googlemaps`